# How to change the background color of a previously selected listview item

Tags: android

I am facing a situation in which I have a ListView item. When I click on one of the listview item a new activity is started which shows detailed information regarding that item. Now when I click back button I come back to the ListView activity. What I need to do is to highlight the list item which I had clicked earlier by changing its background color. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Probably, the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682053/listview-item-wont-stay-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
           //Before starting the new activity change color
           view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
           // Or any other color you placed in value/color.xml file
    }
});
```