# Android: keep blue background after ListView selection

Tags: android, listview, tablet

I have a ListView, and it works great on a phone. Now I am making a tablet UI, with the ListView on the left and details on the right.

When I touch an item, it flashes blue as long as it is pressed. I want to keep that blue color until another item is selected, just like the Gmail app on the Nexus 7.

What is the cleanest way to achieve that? I'd rather avoid setting backgrounds manually, I assume there is a way to mark an element as the "active" one and theme it accordingly.

Comment: You can see this link may helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682053/listview-item-wont-stay-selected

Comment: You can set background color of the view of listview item on the click of listview item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

What you are looking for is known as the "activated" state. To make this work:

Step #1: In `res/values-v11/`, have a style resource that implements `activated`. For example, for a new project that has the `AppTheme` declaration defined there, go with something like:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

    <style name="activated" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Step #2: Define the same style in `res/values/` for any older devices, just as a stub style resource, so references to it continue to work:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>

    <style name="activated" parent="AppTheme"/>

</resources>
```

Step #3: In your layout XML resource for the row in the `ListView`, add `style="@style/activated"` to the list of attributes of the root element

Step #4: Set the `ListView` to be a single-choice list, such as the following line in a `ListFragment`:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

You can see this in action in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Animation/ThreePane), [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Animation/ThreePaneBC), and [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You). For more background on those first two samples, see this SO question: [Complete Working Sample of the Gmail Three-Fragment Animation Scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253965/complete-working-sample-of-the-gmail-three-fragment-animation-scenario)

Comment: It works great, and it's indeed much better than keep changing the background programmatically. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Using

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`

instead of

`R.layout.simple_list_item_checkable_1`.

Just for somebody checking someday.

Answer (score 2):

after days of search and pulling my hair i just found out that `activatedBackgroundIndicator` is also available in ActionBarSherlock styling system. Most of the devs which develop backwards compatible apps, use ActionBarSherlock,so using ActionBarSherlock is a good option for most cases. So instead of using `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` which will give errors in android versions prior to 11, just use: `android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"`

here is the example row layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   //note the activatedBackgroundIndicator
android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:paddingTop="2dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="20dip" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `So instead of using android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator" which will give errors in android versions prior to 11, just use: android:background="?activatedBackgroundIndicator"` What? Can you please explain this?