# How to select an ListView item after long click?

Tags: android, android-listview, selection, onitemclicklistener, contextual-action-bar

I've got a silly little problem. I've registered a `ListFragment` both as `OnItemClickListener` and `OnItemLongClickListener` of its own `ListView`.

When the `onItemClick` event is called, an intent for the detail view activity of that item is started, no problems there.

When the `onItemLongClick`event happens, I want to accomplish the following things:

- Create a CAB
- Keep the long-pressed item selected

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(this.cabMode != null)
        return false;
    this.cabMode = getActivity().startActionMode(editModeCallback);
    view.setSelected(true);
    return true;
}
```

The CAB will show, however, the selection won't stay with the item.

Some bits and pieces, in case they are relevant: I've read about fixing this issue with calls to `view.requestFocusFromTouch()` or using `listView.setItemChecked()`, but that didn't work for me. Also, the views for the list items are instanced from a custom layout, but don't have any custom event listeners attached.

Any help is appreciated. Thx!

Comment: pass selected item position after long press.

Comment: Where should I pass it? `listView.setItemChecked()` takes a position argument,  but calling it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Did you do `ListView.setChoiceMode(...)`? If you don't find a way to fix this, you can always do the selection manually like here http://goo.gl/7aQAn

Comment: No, I did not. Thanks for the pointer. I've tried several combinations of choice modes with calls to either `listView.setItemChecked()` and `view.setSelected()`, but still no effect. I'll have a look at the Sherlock code, however I would think, that what I'm trying to do is so basic that there must be an easy way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but just barely... I actually don't know how such a simple thing can wind up so ridiculously complicated.

The key to the answer can be found here: [Android: keep blue background after ListView selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386333/android-keep-blue-background-after-listview-selection)

What this boils down to is to define an additional style that is used by the `ListView` and setting the choice mode to `AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` (as explained in the linked answer).

This allows you programmatically toggle the selection using `Listview.setItemChecked()`. However, you need to keep track of the index of the touched item in the `onItemLongClick` callback yourself, because `ListView.setSelection()` won't do that (at least `ListView.getSelectedItem()` will always return -1 as far as I can see).

Code (for simplicity, my fragment implements all three `OnItemClickListener`, `OnItemLongClickListener`, and
        `ActionMode.Callback`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
    this.root = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookmarks, container, false);
    this.root.setAdapter(this.listViewAdapter);
    this.root.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    this.root.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    this.root.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    return this.root;
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(this.cabMode != null)
        return false;
    this.selectedPosition = position;
    this.root.setItemChecked(position, true);

    this.root.setOnItemClickListener(null);
    this.cabMode = getActivity().startActionMode(this);
    return true;
}
```

And finally, if you want to get rid of the selection when the CAB is closed:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    cabMode = null;
    this.root.setItemChecked(this.selectedPosition, false);
    this.selectedPosition = -1;
    this.root.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Registering and unregistering the `OnItemClickListener` makes sure that while the CAB is active you won't accidentally trigger the action usually associated with the item (like opening a detail view).

Comment: Chris, note you don't actually need to track the index of the selected item(s). If in choiceMode="singleChoice", use AbsListView.getCheckedItemPosition(). If in choiceMode="multipleChoice", use AbsListView.getCheckedItemPositions() to get the set of checked items. (Note this method is also valid for a single choice mode, but the other method is much simpler.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info! I was too fixated on `ListView.getSelectedItem()` :-)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:(trick)

```
final ListView lvMain = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listTHEMES);
lvMain.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
lvMain.setItemsCanFocus(false);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ArrayTheme);
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (lvMain.isItemChecked(pos)){lvMain.setItemChecked(pos,false);}else{lvMain.setItemChecked(pos,true);}
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"long clicked pos: " + pos);
        //lvMain.setSelection();

        return true;
    }
});
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);
        if (lvMain.isItemChecked(position)){lvMain.setItemChecked(position,false);}else{lvMain.setItemChecked(position,true);}

    }
});
```