# Highlight listview row only on long click

Tags: android

I have implemented a checkable relative layout for a listview much similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742979/how-to-get-a-android-listview-item-selector-to-use-state-checked) and solution. I.e. i extended the relative layout and set its background to a custom selector which chooses a specific background color for "state_checked".

Since i want to use this in conjunction with the contextual action bar (CAB), i want the rows to be checked on the long click rather than the normal click. I can handle this programatically in the long click listener. The (normal) click shall be used to show a detailed view.

However, when i click the row to go to the detailed view, i notice that the row gets highlighted just before the screen transitions to the detailed view. Is there any default behavior which affects "state_checked" in this case and how can i disable it for the (normal) click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580531/how-to-select-an-listview-item-after-long-click

Comment: Handling the long click works as i want it to. My question is why the row is **also** highlighted on the (normal) click.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18549314/1777090)